# How to add gloss to image texture?

Tags: texturing, image

I would like to create a furniture with high gloss front doors. I can add an image texture to the object, so the texture will look like the furniture sheet's texture, but I don't how can I reach a high gloss look. I attach a picture about a real life furniture sheet, where you can see what I mean when I say high gloss. How can I get this look?

Thank you for your help in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's what "coat" option from the Principled BSDF is suppose to do:

Have a look at the manual about layers [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html#layers) and coat [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html#coat).

[image]